# AngularJS filter to ng-repeat, exclude elements, if they in second array

Tags: angularjs, filter

I need filter for ng-repeat, that explode elements in "general" array, if element exist in "suggest" array (by id field).

```js
$scope.general= [{id: 21323, name: 'alex'}, {id: 8787, name: 'maria'}, {id: 8787, name: 'artem'}];

$scope.suggest = [{id: 21323, name: 'alex'}, {id: 8787, name: 'maria'}];
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="elem in general">{{elem.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Need to create a custom filter. What have you tried?

Comment: First, you have duplicate ids, all of them included in second array, in your example. second, you shouldn't do those dynamically in template, because angular will run a lot by $digest cycle. Other than than you can do that like that - `$scope.filteredArray = $scope.general.filter(x => $scope.suggest.find(y => y.id === x.id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) and you'll probably want to use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

You said you wanted to exclude by the property `id`. The following filler optionally allows specifying a property. If the property is not specified, then the objects are excluded by [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator) of the objects.

```
angular.module('myFilters', [])
.filter('exclude', function() {
    return function(input, exclude, prop) {
        if (!angular.isArray(input))
            return input;

        if (!angular.isArray(exclude))
            exclude = [];

        if (prop) {
            exclude = exclude.map(function byProp(item) {
                return item[prop];
            });
        }

        return input.filter(function byExclude(item) {
            return exclude.indexOf(prop ? item[prop] : item) === -1;
        });
    };
});
```

To use this filter in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in general | exclude:suggest:'id'">{{elem.name}}</div>
```

Here is an example jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ov1sjfb/

Note that in your question artem's id matches maria's thus both artem and maria were filtered.  I changed artem's id in the plunker to be unique to show that the filter works.

Comment: Thank you, but i have an error "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" and "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" can you help me?

Comment: This probably means exclude and input are loaded asynchronously, and thus are undefined the first time they are run though the filter. I'll modify the example to handle undefined cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.general = [{
        id: 21323,
        name: 'alex'
    }, {
        id: 8787,
        name: 'maria'
    }, {
        id: 8787,
        name: 'artem'
    }];

    $scope.suggest = [{
        id: 21323,
        name: 'alex'
    }, {
        id: 8787,
        name: 'maria'
    }];
    $scope.filteredArray = function () {
        return $scope.general.filter(function (letter) {
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.suggest.length; i++) {
              return  $scope.suggest[i].id !== letter.id 

            }
        });
    };
}
```

and

```
 <div ng-repeat="elem in filteredArray(letters)">{{elem.name}}</div>
```

check out the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o2er6msv/

Note: please chk ur id, they are duplicated

Comment: Thank you, but Maria should be excluded.

Comment: @trigger what's ur desired solution ?? What should be the output if we consider above 2 arrays mention in question