# Angularjs - NG-repeat with filter to an array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I thought this was going to be the easy part but been going trough google / stack overflow for the past 3 hours with no luck.

I have a straight foward ng-repeat where I want to list everything in my data2 where the ref_id column matches the unique ID of my data1.

```
data1: [ {id: 1, name: "Bob"}, {id: 2, name: "Diane"}, {id: 3, name: "Ross"}, {id: 4, name: "Jimbo"}, ];

data2: [ {ref_id: 1, Result: "Fries"}, {ref_id: 1, Result: "Burger"}, {ref_id: 7, Result: "Burger"}, {ref_id: 8, Result: "Nothing"}, ];
```

So this is what I came up with:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in data2 | filter: { ref_id: data1.id }" > {{ result.Result }} </div>
```

It seems to be ignoring my filter and just spitting out everything. So i thought maybe it dosent like the array in my filter so I created a custom filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in data2 | filter: Test()"  > {{ result.Result }} </div>

$scope.Test = function(item){

  return angular.forEach($scope.data1, function(value, key) {
    return value.id === item.ref_id;
  }

}
```

But this simply does not work either, its giving me undefined variables but I think it dosent like the way I use the function. I just want my ng-repeat to display items that have a matching ID to go with my ref_ID column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you are trying to do:

## 1. Using an `init` method

Creating a list with the required entries in `init` method of the controller (better to use [$onInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#:%7E:text=%24onInit()%20%2D%20Called%20on%20each,initialization%20code%20for%20your%20controller.)), and then using that list in `ng-repeat`

```js
// inside the controller for your app
  $scope.data1 = [ {id: 1, name: "Bob"}, {id: 2, name: "Diane"}, {id: 3, name: "Ross"}, {id: 4, name: "Jimbo"}];

  $scope.data2 = [ {ref_id: 1, Result: "Fries"}, {ref_id: 1, Result: "Burger"}, {ref_id: 7, Result: "Burger"}, {ref_id: 8, Result: "Nothing"}];

  var init = function () {
    var idList = $scope.data1.map(function (item) {
      return item.id;    
    });
    $scope.filteredList = $scope.data2.filter(function (item) {
      return idList.includes(item.ref_id);
    });
  }
  init();
// end of controller
```

And in view:

```html
<div ng-repeat="result in filteredList" > {{ result.Result }} </div>
```

## 2. Making a custom filter

```js
angular.module('yourModuleName', []).filter('test', function() {
    return function(input, include, prop1, prop2) {
        if (!angular.isArray(input))
            return input;

        if (!angular.isArray(include))
            include = [];

        if (prop2) {
            // extracting 'id' from data1
            include = include.map(function byProp(item) {
                return item[prop2];
            });
        }
        return input.filter(function (item) {
          // checking if ref_id of current item is present in include, which is a list of ids from data1
          return include.includes(item[prop1])
        });
    };
});
```

- `input` is list used in `ng-repeat`
- `include`, `prop1` and `prop2` correspond to the parameters used while calling the filter

Using the filter in view:

```html
  <div ng-repeat="result in data2 | test:data1:'ref_id':'id'" > {{ result.Result }} </div>
```

- `data2` corresponds to `input` in filter definition
- `include` corresponds to `data1` sent it through the filter
- `'ref_id'` (string) corresponds to prop1
- `'id'` (string) corresponds to prop2

I picked the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991760/angularjs-filter-to-ng-repeat-exclude-elements-if-they-in-second-array) and modified it to fit this use case. Hope this helps.

Here's a plnkr including code for both of the above cases: https://plnkr.co/edit/GdvVZIhDbFTaVQPY

Reference for understanding use of multiple filter arguments: [How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$scope.Test = function(item){
  var idList = $scope.data1.map(function (item) {
      return item.id;    
    });
   return $scope.data2.filter(function (item) {
      return idList.includes(item.ref_id);
    });
}  
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="result in Test()"  > {{ result.Result }} </div>
```